# How to destruct object containing self-referential pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, destructor, delete-operator

I have a tree node structure which is simply defined as:

```
typedef struct TreeNode {
    int data;
    TreeNode *left;
    TreeNode *right;
    TreeNode *parent;

    TreeNode(int);
    ~TreeNode();
} TreeNode;
```

To free memory pointed by the `left`, `right`, and `parent` objects upon destruction (assuming not null), I made a destructor as follows:

```
TreeNode::~TreeNode() {
    delete left;
    delete right;
    delete parent;
}
```

However, doing so causes the control to infinitely recursively delete the `TreeNode` objects since those `delete` statements inside the destructor calls the destructor of the same structure.

---

**Question:**

- What is the proper way of freeing self-referential pointers, specifically inside the destructor?

Comment: You would do well to read up on `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `Tree` class that contains `TreeNode`'s, and the `Tree` class creates and destroys nodes when necessary?  Your current design unravels the whole tree with the deletion of a single node.  What if you want to delete just one node?

Comment: @Jesper I'm really just starting with C++, so until I know the basics, only then will I move to the more advanced stuff :D

Comment: @Christian Handling owning raw pointers and manually managing memory with `new` and `delete` *is* the advanced stuff.

Comment: @Christian You misunderstand. I'm trying to point you in the direction of the *simple* solution. You have started down the *hard* path by using (old-school) manual memory management.

Comment: @ PaulMcKenzie Actually I have a `Tree` class. But in the end, it still boils down to the above problem since inside the `Tree` class' method, I'll just be calling `delete` to the particular node I'm wanted to destroy. And calling `delete` on that `'TreeNode` is where the problem arises.

Comment: @Corristo Well I'm the type of  person who wants to learn the hard way first ;)

Comment: @Christian -- No it doesn't boil down to the problem you've stated.  The `TreeNode` in my scenario should have no destructor at all.  All the nodes are controlled by the `Tree` class.   When the `Tree` deletes a `TreeNode`, it will delete only that `TreeNode`.  If it needs to delete a bunch of nodes, i.e. the `Tree` is being destroyed, then the `Tree` class does so in a loop.  None of this unraveling the whole thing from a `TreeNode`, like a loose thread on a sweater.

Comment: @Christian I still suggest you start with an implementation using `std::unique_ptr`, and when you got that working you can always replace them with owning raw pointers, `new` and `delete` later.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The `Tree::delete_node` function still needs to do some special handling because you can't just delete a node in the middle. The children of the deleted node need to be relocated to a new parent, but that can't always be the parent of the deleted node itself, since it might already have an additional child. If you're relocating the children first and then destroy the node everything works fine. No need to not clean up in the destructor. Of course that can lead to stack overflows if the tree is too deep, but I'd recommend to get the easy solution working first before optimizing.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way is to not use owning raw pointers, use `std::unique_ptr` for the children instead.

If you also get rid of the superfluous `typedef`, the struct looks like this:

```
struct TreeNode {
    int data;
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> left;
    std::unique_ptr<TreeNode> right;
    TreeNode *parent{nullptr};

    TreeNode() = default;
};
```

Now you don't need to do anything, the compiler will generate the correct deconstructor for you.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you don't call the parent destructor. But then, as mentioned above, the entire tree below that node will be deleted.

Comment: Any comment on downvoting?

Comment: Calling the parent destructor or not, as long as I call to delete a tree node somewhere in the parent's method; it causes the control to 'recurse' infinitely.

Comment: You're wrong, since it should stop if there are no more linked subobjects `if(left){delete left;left=0;}`